# Runtime upgrade error: system.FailedToExtractRuntimeVersion

Tags: runtime-upgrade, error

Our goal is to migrate pallet code to the newer Substrate version and keep the block history (since ~ august 2020).

[Old Substrate ver. (10.02.2021)](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/commit/49a4103f4bfef55be20a5c6d26e18ff3003c3353) -> [New Substrate ver. (14.01.2022)](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/commit/afb74de23dfe2994e7ce38c0870efb9734e966f7)

For such purpose, we've created a brand new repo with the new structure and newer Substrate version. Recently the code migration was finished.

Right now, we are trying to upgrade the runtime of our testnet nodes and getting the `FailedToExtractRuntimeVersion` error while calling `setCode` extrinsic.

**What should be changed in the runtime from the new repo** in order to generate a valid Wasm which will be accepted by the node?

Attributes `spec_name`, `spec_version`, and `authoring_version` are the same between Wasm and native.

**Should we update the node (native binary) first?**

We tried to do so and run the new node with the original `chain_spec`, but JSON structure was different (got `unknown key` errors).

Comment: Hey, could you please open an issue in Substrate. But your idea of first updating the node sounds good. You should compare a chain spec generated by the newer node vs your old chain spec and check on the differences.

Answer (score 2):

We've managed to upgrade the runtime and save the block history.
It's still not clear what was the exact root cause, but we've created a runtime from scratch and added all of the FRAME pallets. After upgrading the node in the first place, the runtime was upgraded successfully.